# R Shiny renderDataTable show two decimal places and center align all data

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to only show two decimal places for all data in my table and align everything centrally. The first column is countries, but the rest are numbers. This is the code

```
output$Composite <- renderDataTable(FVI_DATA_COMPOSITE, options = list(pageLength = 15,lengthChange=FALSE))
```

Any idea how to do that?

Edit: This does not work.

```
output$Composite <- renderDataTable(FVI_DATA_COMPOSITE, 
  options = list(pageLength = 10,lengthChange=FALSE), round(FVI_DATA_COMPOSITE[3:9], digits=2)
```

Comment: You could use `round` function to round the data.

Comment: I think I tried that but couldnt get it work. How would you suggest implementing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
output$Composite <- renderDataTable(datatable(FVI_DATA_COMPOSITE, 
  options = list(pageLength = 10,lengthChange=FALSE)) %>% formatRound(c(3:9), 2)
```

[Documentation here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html)

Edit: To center align

```
output$Composite <- renderDataTable(datatable(FVI_DATA_COMPOSITE, 
      options = list(pageLength = 10,lengthChange=FALSE)) %>%
      formatRound(c(3:9), 2) %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c(3:9), 'text-align' = 'center')
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Made an error about closure

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. Last thing, do you know how center align all of the data in the same columns where rounding happens?

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer's code pattern kept returning the following warning/error:

> `Warning: Error in : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

I had to use a slightly different pattern within a Shiny `app.R` file:

```r
server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$dtable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(FVI_DATA_COMPOSITE) %>% 
      formatRound(columns = c(3:9), digits = 2)
  })

}
```